# Class does not exist when using service inside compiler pass

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony

I noticed some weired behaviour that even might be a bug in symfony? I don't know... here are the steps to reprocuce:

### 1. Install symfony

I have a fresh install of symfony 3.1.3, installed with the cli installer:

```
$ symfony new myproject
```

### 2. Add some service

I added a service definition in `app/config/services.yml`:

```
services:
    app.helper:
        class: AppBundle\Service\AppHelper
        arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

And I added the corresponding service class:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class AppHelper
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    }

    /**
     * Returns stuff.
     *
     * @param $key
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getStuff($key)
    {
        return $this->em->... // get stuff
    }
}
```

In the constructor I inject the container and get doctrines entity manager from it. Works fine so far, inside of controllers for example.

### 3. Add compiler pass

Then I added a compiler class with an empty process method:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;


use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class MenuItemCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /**
     * Collect modules menu items.
     *
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
    }
}
```

And I added it to the bundle class:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle;

use AppBundle\DependencyInjection\MenuItemCompilerPass;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new MenuItemCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

### 4. Implement failing code

Now I want to access the `AppHelper` service inside the `process` method of `MenuItemCompilerPass`:

```
/**
 * Collect modules menu items.
 *
 * @param ContainerBuilder $container
 */
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $stuff = $container->get('app.helper')->getStuff('something');
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
ReflectionException in ContainerBuilder.php line 862: Class does not exist
```

As it turns out, when I remove

```
$this->em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

from the constructor in `AppHelper` it works again.

Can someone tell what the problem is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Never ever* get services from the container in a compiler pass. Only work with the definitions.

<s>However, you can get the parameters from the container. So instead of doing `$host = $container->get('app.helper')->getParameter('database_host');`, simply do `$host = $container->getParameter('database_host');`</s>

Also, *never ever* inject the container in a service. Just inject the `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager` service directly.

Comment: :D Well... thats true... but the parameters are not the point... I removed the confusing code.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer both *never ever* statements still hold true. Can you add your actual use-case to your question? (I can't imagine you only want to get the value from the container when the cache is built, you probably want to use something else than a compiler pass)

Comment: Services can be tagged as menu items, also a @MenuItem annotation can be added to controller actions to automatically generate a menu item for that action.  The compiler pass then collects all these and passes them to a menu builder service. I need this in a larger crm context.

Comment: you should use an event for this in your menu service, you cant actually use any services like doctrine yet during compile time. [check the knpMenuBundle documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/events.html) they do exactly what you need to do.